# Ansible Find any member of list in string

Tags: ansible

I have a problem where I need to only accept a task when any member of a list of IPS is found in registred result from a uri request, the list is generated dymanically and of variable size, the url is a aggregator of  different microservices so it will take time until it is populated (thus the retries and delays)

```
vars:
   ES_IPS: ["192.168.0.1","192.168.0.2","192.168.0.3"]  #dynamic (this is an example)
- name: Check if any member exists
  uri:
     url: http://localhost:8080/stuff
     method: GET 
     return_content: yes 
     status_code: 200 
  register: result
  until: any of ES_IPS in result.content <-------- (this here)
  retries: 100 
  delay: 10
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is the number of elements in the `ES_IPS` list fixed? always 3 as in your code?

Comment: no, it dynamically generated and variable size ,or else I would have a done bunch of "or's".

Comment: test environment is down, my work mentioned below will be delayed until tomorrow.

Answer (score -1):

Please look there:

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html

I think that you should use one of playbooks filters. Did you try:  `until: result.stdout.find("what you want") != -1` ?

You can also use `command` module:

```
- command: "grep  {{ result.content }} ..."
  with_items: "..."
  register: new_result
```

In Ansible existing also substrings:

```
when: variable1 | search("value")
when: '"value" in variable1'
when: fsm_out.stdout | regex_search(' data')
```

Comment: the issue is not finding, the issue is find "any" and then it returns true for the task to continue. if I grep after the task to continue, the task already passed whether the site has began aggregating ips or not. also it shouldn't be a "when" it should be an "until", your answer though have made think of a way that might be work. If it works, I will post the answer here.

Comment: Look here please: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html#when-should-i-use-also-how-to-interpolate-variables-or-dynamic-variable-names